# Good practices for a flexible search page - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, filter, django-queryset

I'm just wondering if there is any example I could take from others on the topic.

I have a page within Django which uses filters, in order to perform searches.

At the moment I'm doing a simple check for the GET parameters and adding a .filter() to a queryset accordingly:

```
if color:
  query.filter(color=color)
```

---

This feels a bit like an ugly way to do, and I've been a bit stuck wondering how I could make it more dynamic.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALLOWED = ('color', 'size', 'model')
kwargs = dict(
    (key, value)
    for key, value in request.GET.items()
    if key in ALLOWED
)
query.filter(**kwargs)
```

This will allow you to make requests like this `/search/?color=red&size=1` or `/search/?model=Nikon&color=black`.

Comment: no way! this is great! Can you use dicts with any function, by using the method you just shown me?

Comment: any suggestions for DateTime?

Comment: You can, but you can't use international characters as keyword argument's names, if you want to do this, you should use this syntax:

    def test(**kwargs):
      param = kwargs['параметр']
      # do something.

Comment: For date-time you need to add parsing. Use http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/1.5 for this. The code will be a little more complex.