# Arbitrary number of search terms

Tags: python, regex, django, filter

I'm trying to make a view that will take in an arbitrary number of search terms, and filter a specific object with those terms.

What I'm thinking is that the url will have a pattern that looks something like the following: `/[property]=[value]/[property]=[value]/...` where this pattern could go on for as long as the user wants. I can then parse this by doing something like: `search=match.split('/')`. Then I'll iterate through each item in search, something along the lines of:

```
results=myObject.objects.all()
for item in search:
    items=item.split('=')
    results=results.filter(items[0]=items[1])
```

Unfortunately I'm being told that keywords can't be expressions. Is there a way that I can have the keyword be a variable? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "Unfortunately I'm being told that keywords can't be expressions"?

Comment: He wants to pass keyword arguments where `items[0]` is a keyword and `items[1]` is its value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good practices for a flexible search page - Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202922/good-practices-for-a-flexible-search-page-django)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pre-construct your keyword arguments as a dictionary, and pass that using the `**` syntax.

```
>>> items = ['a','b','c']
>>> def print_kwargs(**kwargs):
...   for key,value in kwargs.iteritems():
...     print "%s = %s" % (key, value)
...
>>> d = {items[0] : items[1]}
>>> print_kwargs(**d)
a = b
```

For your example:

```
d = {}
for item in search:
    items = item.split('=')
    d[items[0]] = items[1]
results = results.filter(**d)
```

Comment: That's excellent! Thanks. One more question. If I need to filter based on an attribute that is in an object held within that object (that is, I have object A, which has a foreign key reference to object B, and I need to filter based on an attribute held by object B) how would I do that? If I didn't need to use a kwarg, it would be relatively simple, just `results.filter(B__property=value)`. How could I do that using a dictionary?

Comment: @dar2162 I'll preface this with the fact that I don't know Django but if it would really simply be `B__property=value` then just add that key value pair to the dictionary like `d[B__property]=value` before passing it to filter. This dictionary can contain any key value pairs you want treated as keyword arguments.

Comment: Fantastic! Although, it needed to be a concatenated string, ie `property='B__%s' %items[0]` then `d[property]=items[1]`